# Using transactional bus inside consumer

Tags: masstransit

I have REST API gateway which calls one of the microservices with MassTransit request client. This request is not durable and is meant to live for a short time - essentially it's just replacement of "traditional" synchronous (via HTTP/GRPC/etc) gateway-microservice communication.

On microservice side I have consumer which under the hood uses DbContext and Transaction (EFC) to perform some work in database. After the work is done it should publish "WorkDoneEvent" (to be consumed later by other microservices) and return result of the work to api gateway. Event must be published atomically along with transaction used to perform the work. It does not matter if ApiGateway will receive response / will retry request - as soon as transaction is commited both work result and sending "WorkDoneEvent" must be guaranteed.

Normally this is done with transactional outbox which first saves published event to database within same transaction as the work is done. (And then some process constantly "polls" outbox and tries send message to the broker, when done it removes message from outbox). As far as I know.

MassTransit seems to have transactional outbox built in: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/transactions.html#transactional-bus.

However in docs it clearly states:

> Never use the TransactionalBus or TransactionalEnlistmentBus when writing consumers. These tools are very specific and should be used only in the scenarios described.

And this is exactly what I want to do...

Why I should not do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the InMemoryOutbox, which is part of MassTransit. It's significantly lighter weight, is designed to work in a consumer, and will not publish your events until after the consumer has completed (but prior to acknowledging the message at the broker). The only consideration is that your consumer should be idempotent (which needs to be the case in your approach as well) and if the operation was already performed on a retry, it should republish the events.

There are [videos](https://youtu.be/P41IsVAc1nI), [articles](https://masstransit-project.com/articles/outbox.html), and a [sample](https://github.com/phatboyg/Trashlantis) to go along with it.

Comment: I read about memory outbox but still I don't get it - what if db transaction in consumer succeeds and one microsecond after the whole system goes down (broker, consumer service, gateway service). Client receives timeout error from gateway and info that something bad happened. Since this was short-lived request-response message it expires after let's say 20s. The system goes up and we end up with commited data in database, empty broker and no info if "WorkDone" event was sent to the broker or not. Memory outbox can work only if request-response is durable and stays in the broker (not expires)?

Comment: "short-lived request/response" and "durable storage in database" shouldn't be used in the same paragraph...

Comment: Ok I think I get it now: you mean that successful "request" (sent to broker) should already guarantee that it will be processed (and it does since it's durable). In my case which is API GW <=> microservice communication, it's the "response"  which can be safely discarded after some timeout (also consumer can ignore any errors caused by sending response).

Comment: Exactly - if the timeout has passed, the API connection is gone, the response is extra. The durable command will still be processed/retried/etc. based upon receive endpoint configuration and not lost.